# how to have wait_until die if time out

Tags: selenium, perl

```
use Selenium::Waiter 'wait_until';
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;
$selen = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new( ... );

$elem = wait_until { $selen->find_element('//h1[@class="banner-heading"]') };
```

In the above code, if the element being looked for is not found, or the `wait_until` times out, I want to the script to die.  How can I make this happen?  The default behaviour of `wait_until` is to return an empty string if it times out.

Answer (score 4):

As `Selenium::Waiter` docs say [on die-ing](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Waiter#Dying)

> PLEASE check the return value before proceeding, as we unwisely suppress any attempts your BLOCK may make to die or croak. The BLOCK you pass is called in a `"try" in Try::Tiny`, and if any of the invocations of your function throw and the BLOCK never becomes true, we'll carp exactly once at the end immediately before returning false.

and then proceed to allow us to bail out

> If you want to die anyways, just pass die => 1 to wait_until instead:
>
> ```
> # Dies on the first failure, do your own error handling:
> wait_until { die 'oops' } die => 1;
> ```

I've tested it and it works.  One can also adjust wait period and intervals for re-tries.

Note the docs' warning to make sure that `implicit_wait` from `Selenium::Remote::Driver` is set to a low value (it is by default but if
[set_implicit_wait_timeout](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver#set_implicit_wait_timeout) is called that may be changed).

As for die-ing on failing to [find_element](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver#find_element), the `Selenium::Remote::Driver` does that by default

> If the element cannot be found, we will CROAK, killing your script.

So

```
my $elem = wait_until { $selen->find_element(...) } die => 1;
```

should do what you need.

Comment: I want `wait_until` to die when it times out. The default behaviour is to return an empty string.

Comment: @CJ7 Did you read the answer?  If you run it with `die => 1` then _it does `die`_ when it times out.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have a problem using `find_elements` going into an array. eg. `@elems = wait_until { $selen->find_elements('//table/tbody/tr') }` The elements of the resulting array don't seem to work properly. I am getting an 'unblessed reference' error.  Without the `wait_until` it works fine.

Comment: @CJ7 Ah ... perhaps it times out too soon for the particular search? Try increasing the timeout, and (or?) perhaps the `interval` (so that it just simply waits for it). Like `wait_until { ... } timeout => 60, interval => 60` ...?  Just a guess, I don't know what else it could be.  It does use `Try::Tiny` and I have seen strange things with it.  If it's still a bother implement your own (with `alarm`)?

Comment: I think `wait_until` doesn't work when the function returns a list/array.

Comment: @CJ7 Indeed, it returns in scalar context (seen in the source to be imposed [here](https://metacpan.org/dist/Selenium-Remote-Driver/source/lib/Selenium/Waiter.pm#L33)), confirmed as: I return an array, `my @ret = wait_until { my @ary = 5..7; @ary };`, but `@ret` only has one element -- the length of the array `@ary` that I returned (`3`).  Then make a reference of the list that should be returned and return that, the reference-- `my $ret_ref = wait_until { my @ary = 5..7; \@ary };` (or just `{ [ 5..7 ] }` if values are made on the fly)